# outline for patches in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to create outlines for patches? I want a simple grid with white background and black lines.

I managed to create a grid from a code I found but the turtles walked on the lines instead of inside the squares.

Comment: Can you please show your work first?

Comment: Patches do not have shapes in NetLogo by design. If you'd like to draw a grid around patches, you would need to create a turtle, use the pen primitives, and walk over the edges of all patches with that turtle, which can be done with a simple loop. Alternatively, you can try to create a checkerboard with a code like `ask patches with [(pxcor + pycor) mod 2 = 0][set pcolor white]`.

Comment: Thanks. It just seemed such a trivial request to me that I was sure there would be such an option.

Answer (score 5):

There is a somewhat silly but effective way to get patch outlines using a specific turtle shape and [the `stamp` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#stamp).

### Option 1

The custom shape is a square outline that fills the full size of the turtle's area, which at a `size` of 1 (the default) is the same as a patch area.  I called the shape `"square-outline"` in my sample model.  Here is the relevant code:

```
to test
  clear-all
  ask patches [ sprout 1 [
    set shape "square-outline"
    if outline-color != black [
      set color outline-color 
    ]
    stamp
    die
  ]]
end
```

I use `stamp` and have the turtles `die` so you don't have to worry about them in the rest of your code.  You could leave them alive if that made sense for your model.

And [here is the sample model to play with on NetLogo Web](https://netlogoweb.org/launch#https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LaCuneta/82b621344c7a2ccd9ec41a280673dbbf/raw/548d1eec536fa9793c32d5e6602c09c47596e597/Patch%2520outlines.nlogo) and get the shape from if you want to try it out.  You can export that nlogo file and use the **Import from Model...** feature in [the turtle shapes editor](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/shapes.html) to get the shape into your model.

### Option 2

Edit:  I updated the model with an option to hide/show each edge of the outline.  I did this by adding a rotating `"patch-edge"` shape that only occupied one edge of the turtle shape.  I then can set each edge by setting the turtle's `heading` to one of 0 (top), 90 (right), 180 (bottom), or 270 (left) before stamping it.

```
to test
  clear-all
  ask patches [ sprout 1 [
    if outline-color != black [
      set color outline-color
    ]
    ifelse top-edges? and right-edges? and bottom-edges? and left-edges? [
      stamp-square-outline
    ] [
      if top-edges?    [ stamp-edge 0   ]
      if right-edges?  [ stamp-edge 90  ]
      if bottom-edges? [ stamp-edge 180 ]
      if left-edges?   [ stamp-edge 270 ]
    ]
    die
  ]]
end

to stamp-square-outline
  set shape "square-outline"
  stamp
end

to stamp-edge [h]
  set shape "patch-edge"
  set heading h
  stamp
end
```

### Option 2 Expanded Example

I wanted to make a more extensive example of outlining patch shapes so I extended the sample model with a `make-shapes` procedure to create a blob of grey patches, then to use the `neighbors4` primitive and `towards` primitive to draw borders between different patches.  The sample model code is updated, and here is the relevant portion:

```
breed [decors decor]

to make-shapes
  clear-all
  
  ; setup the decorator to use to draw edges
  create-decors 1
  let decorator one-of decors

  ; create some grey blobs of shapes we want to outline
  let start-count 0.1 * count patches
  ask n-of start-count patches [ set pcolor grey ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = black] [
    let odds (0.1 + count neighbors4 with [pcolor = grey]) / 5
    if (random-float 1) < odds [ set pcolor grey ]
  ]
  
  ; detect the edges between grey and black patches and outline them
  ask patches with [pcolor = grey] [
    ask decorator [ 
      move-to myself 
      ifelse outline-color != black [
        set color outline-color
      ] [
        set color one-of base-colors 
      ]
    ]
    ask neighbors4 with [pcolor = black] [
      ; `towards` gets a heading from the black patch back, so some
      ; simple math reverses it for stamping the edge.
      let h ((towards myself) + 180) mod 360
      ask decorator [ stamp-edge h ]
    ]
  ]
  ; darker grey just looks a little nicer
  ask patches with [pcolor = grey] [ set pcolor grey - 3 ]
  
  ; keep the decorator from interfering with the rest of the model
  ask decorator [ die ]
end
```

Comment: This is a very nice procedure for a common problem, thanks @Jasper. Question: is it possible to tweak it so that only one side of the turlte-patch gets outlined instead of all four ? (while keeping if possible the squared shape)

Comment: @lomper Sure, I updated the answer and sample model with a second option.