# How to create links between turtles and patches?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have the following code, which gives turtles property over patches. Does anyone know how to either create links between the turtle and its owned patches?

Or, even better, to create a line that surrounds the patches that belong to the turtle?

I tried the following code but it gives an error because  `CREATE-LINKS-WITH expected input to be a turtle agentset but got the agentset (agentset, 25 patches) instead.` It seems that links with patches are not allowed. Any thoughts?

```
patches-own [
  state 
  patch-owner  
]

turtles-own [
 property 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [
    move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
  ]
  setup-patches
  set-ownership
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    let closest-turtle min-one-of turtles [distance myself]
    set patch-owner closest-turtle
  ]
end

to set-ownership
  ask turtles [
    let my-patches patches with [patch-owner = myself]
     create-links-with my-patches
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that one can not create a link from turtle to patch or patch to patch.  However, the typical way of doing the same thing is to place a turtle on the patch and to link to that turtle.  To avoid confusion, it's best to make those "patch turtles" a different breed.  So, you might do something like

```
breed [locations location]

    to set-ownership
      ask turtles [
        let my-patches patches with [patch-owner = myself]
        ask my-patches [
          sprout-locations 1
        ]
        create-links-with locations with [member patch-here my-patches]
        ]
      ]
```

If you want you can make the location turtles invisible, or a certain shape or color.

Outlining patches is not trivial - see here:
[outline for patches in NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462356/outline-for-patches-in-netlogo)
Would simply coloring the patches help?

Comment: This works perfect, thank you, Charles. I combined it with the post on turtle shapes also that you provided it, and now work entirely with the `locations` breed instead of the patches.